# Hide / Target feature for specific Site Template

Tags: 2013, feature, branding

I have created a branding solution which contains 2 features. One is for the MySites root site collection and the other is for any other Site Collection type.

I do not want people activating the MySites feature in a regular site collection. Is there any way to target my features based on the Site Collection Type / Template or ID? This way, the MySites feature would not show in a regular site collection's feature list

Comment: Do you have both Mysites and team sites in one web app? why not mark the feature as hidden?

Comment: Different Web Apps. If I mark as hidden? How would I activate it?

Comment: Powershell, as long as you have the GUID

Answer (score 1):

So i think, you can use **"Feature Stapling / Feature Site Template Association"** options. this way you can associate it to a site template.
We had the same thing for our SP 2010 deployment for mysite, i am not developer so i dont know insider information.

Here are good resource:

[Feature Stapling / Feature Site Template Association](http://balaonweb.blogspot.com/2012/12/feature-stapling-feature-site-template.html)

[Feature/Site Template Associations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa544538.aspx)

http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/feature-stapling-in-sharepoint-2010